# Installing brew on Mac 10.6 results in syntax error

Tags: homebrew, osx-snow-leopard

Running the following command from http://brew.sh/:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

...result in:

> -e:192: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting $end
>                  .map { |d| File.join(HOMEBREW_PREFIX, d) }
>                   ^

I'm using zsh on Mac OS 10.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official homebrew install command use some [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism). The easiest way to solve this is to run the homebrew install command with `bash -c` in front of it :

```
bash -c '/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"'
```

Answer (score 5):

ok so to install manually through terminal do

```
$ cd /usr/local

$ mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

then you need to change your bash_profile like this:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

you might need to change permissions to the homebrew folder as well:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/homebrew
```

this worked for me

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that the OP (Original Poster) use zsh and not bash.

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward to 2020 and homebrew is no longer ruby based, but bash-based. Also, it officially only supports 10.13 or higher, while keeping an eye out for 10.9 users.

The new way to get homebrew on 10.6 or lower is by using TigerBrew:
https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew

This is a maintained fork of homebrew, with the purpose of offering support for 10.4-10.7.

After installing tigerbrew, install a newer curl: `brew install curl`.
That should fix any ssl issues.